# How do we debug a 3rd party ruby gems in a Windows machine

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am running a Ruby gem in a Windows virtual machine. 
This is a 3rd party gem used to integrate 2 systems (servicenow and nexpose).
I have no expertise in Ruby or Ruby gems so let me know how we can do this.

Answer (score 2):

You have the gems on your local machine.

1. Run `bundle open gem_name` and you will open the gem source code. If you don't configure a text editor for this command you will have to do it. Add a break point where you want to debug) byebug or debugger for example).
2. In the `Gemfile` of your main app find the gem you just changed. Add the `path` option to it -> `gem_name, path: 'local_machine_path_to_the_gem`.
3. Run `bundle install` again.
4. Start debugging by testing the code that calla the gem.

Comment: i get this message




'bundle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

when i run the below command

C:\Users\USERNAME>bundle open nexpose_servicenow

Comment: Did you run `gem install bundler` ?

Comment: Instead of adding the `path:`, just restart the server and re-run the code. It might trigger the break-point. Tested on Ruby `v2.7.3` and Rails `v6.1.7.6`.